# production.log empty on Rails 4 / Capistrano / Passenger / Nginx server (digital ocean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, logging, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I have set up a rails 4 server on Ubuntu 12.04 using Capistrano, Nginx, Passenger, Postgres, Redis/Resque

Everything is working great, except that the production.log file is always empty.

I have tried a variety of configuration changes in production.rb to no avail.

It's definitely not a permissions issue, as the permissions on both the log dir and each of the logs are wide open (777)

Can anyone hep me figure out how to get basic logging working?

Comment: wish there is a way to exclude obsolete questions and answer from this site

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The culprit was [Heroku's rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem

Removing that gem from the Gemfile, now the logs are working as expected.

```
# group :production do
#   gem 'rails_12factor'
# end
```

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, the `rails_12factor` gem was responsible, but that's only because it includes `rails_stdout_logging`, which is the real culprit, however, due to it's *intended* behavior to "[ensure that your logs will be sent to standard out](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging#why-is-this-needed)."

Answer (score 2):

Check with the log levels in production.rb file, `config.log_level = :debug` will display it's errors. Also make sure the server is running production mode, in case you have not made any changes any configuration files for rails env, production mode is by default.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GhostRider, but the problem was with the rails_12factor gem, bah!