# why my Rails production log is empty on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I deployed an application on AWS EC2, I'm using Capistrano for deployment. However, the production log on my local machine is empty. According to [production.log empty on Rails 4 / Capistrano / Passenger / Nginx server (digital ocean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670173/production-log-empty-on-rails-4-capistrano-passenger-nginx-server-digital), I removed rails_12factor from Gemfile in production, but it is still not working.

I actually really confused, because, according to many related replies on Stack Overflow, production log seems automatically appear in the production.log on my local machine, I'm wondering how it happens? If my assumption is incorrect, then where can I see the production log.

I used rails 4.2.2.

Comment: "where can I see the production log" -  on production server. That EC2 box of yours.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how to do so, I tried search resources but I didnt find any tutorial on how to do so.

Comment: What you want to google is "how to ssh into ec2 server" (or something similar). Once you're in the remote shell, the rest is easy.

Comment: Maybe capistrano has shortcuts for this. Check their documentation too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is this the answer?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/25693476/8521403  , this guy mentioned about  
 a path "public/system", is the dir on my remote server or on my local machine?

Comment: No, the tip from that answer won't help make production.log appear on your local machine. In fact, you might as well give up this idea now. This is just not done. To get production log, you'll have to ssh into production box, one way or another. (or use a log shipping/aggregation service, but that's next step architecture)